# getIntent() always returns null

Tags: java, android

This code starts the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("load", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is how I try to get the intent in the new activity:

```
private Intent intent = this.getIntent();
```

I was told to try and include:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

But it doesn|t help. After several crashes I added:

```
if (intent == null) Log.w("Intent", "Intent is null");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read about the functionality of [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) before you use it wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Intent intent = this.getIntent();
```

Call `getIntent()` inside `onCreate` or in another callback of the life cycle.

Comment: Thank you for this. I moved this line to onCreate() and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
private boolean value =getIntent().getBoolean("load");
```